# Is there any way to extract only one file (or a regular expression) from tar file

Tags: unix

I have a **tar.gz** file.
Because of space issues and the time required extract is longer, I need to extract only the selected file.

I have tried the below

```
grep -l '<text>' *
file1
file2
```

only **file1,file2** should be extracted.

What should I Do to SAVE all the tail -f data to a FILE swa3?
I have swa1.out which has list of online data inputs.
swa2 is a file which should skip the keywords from swa1.
swa3 is a file where it should write the data.
Can anyone help in this?
I have tried below commnad, but I'm not able to get it

```
tail -f SWA1.out |grep -vf SWA2 >> swa3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do this with --extract option like this

```
tar --extract --file=test.tar.gz main.c
```

> Here in --file , specify the .gz filename and at the end specify the
>   filename you want to extract.